# Unable to copy and paste from one workbook to another (shared drive)

Tags: excel, vba

I created a workbook containing a macro that can copy a range from a source file and paste it to a destination file, both being on a shared drive. I get the error: Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

I know that the issue doesn't come from finding the workbooks because after the macro crashes they are both open on my desktop.

Here is my code:

```vb
Dim source As Workbook, source_filepath As String, source_filename As String
Dim destination As Workbook, dest_filepath As String, dest_filename As String, scen_name As String


'Set the location and name of the source file
source_filepath = InputBox("Enter the file path for the source scenario file", "Source file directory")
    If source_filepath = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

source_filename = InputBox("Paste the name of the source scenario file here", "Source file name")
    If source_filename = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


'Set the location and name of the destination file
dest_filepath = InputBox("Enter the file path for the destination scenario file", "Destination file directory")
    If dest_filepath = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

dest_filename = InputBox("Name to give the destination scenario file", "Destination file name")
    If dest_filename = "" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If


Set source = Application.Workbooks.Open(source_filepath & "\" & source_filename & ".xlsx")


Set destination = Workbooks.Add
destination.SaveAs Filename:=dest_filepath & "\" & dest_filename & ".xlsx"

'I tried all these different ways of copy&pasting, they all get the Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

source.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 34).Copy destination.Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value

source.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 34).Copy _
destination: destination.Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value

source.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, 34).Copy
destination.Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought looking at your code is:

```
source.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Resize(1,34).Copy destination.Sheet1.Cells(1,1).Value
```

should be

```
source.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Resize(1,34).Copy destination.Sheet1.Cells(1,1)
```

You don't need

```
.Value
```

at the end.
Let me know if this works :)

Comment: Hi Emily, thanks for bringing that to my attention, but the problem still remains.